# Best way to edit package.json file for Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I get a parsing error when attempting to deploy a cloud function that the firebase-tools module cannot be found. I looked in my package.json file and notice that it's missing, so I want to add it. I also noticed that the other dependencies have versions specified.

Are these version numbers updated automatically when I update my cloud functions through the CLI with `npm install --save firebase-functions@latest`?

And what is the proper way for me to add `firebase-tools` as a dependency? Do I specify a version number?

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.20.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Now is probably a good time for you to become familiar with how npm works at a high level.  It's a generalized tool for package management for node projects, and not specific to Firebase at all.  Once you understand npm, working with Cloud Functions projects should be more clear.

Comment: @DougStevenson where can I find a list of dependencies that Firebase Cloud Functions supports? For example, how can I find the latest version number of `firebase-tools`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way is to use NPM, the NodeJS package manager:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Where switch `-g` means global (available to all projects), not referenced inside `package.json`.
Also see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools ...which reads version `11.0.0`.